# Excel - Count the number of instances of order status

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

[image: Sales Order Data]

I have the above sales order data which lists a day by day update of orders as they go through each stage until shipped. Orders 1 and 2 are shown alongside the status of that order for each date between 1st and 08th February.

What I need to do (in a pivot eventually), is to count the number of days for each order that they were in each state. So for example Sales number 1 was in a processing state for 4 days and a packed state for 3 days and then finally a shipped state for 1 day. I want these 3 numbers displayed beside each status maybe on a separate line?

For example

Sales Number 1

Processing - 4 Days

Packed - 3 Days

Shipped - 1 Day

You'll also notice that on Sales Number 2, the order went back into a "On Hold" state, this can occur in my dataset so just count it as normal e.g On Hold - 2 days.

How would I get this count using a formula or pivot etc?

Comment: Look into MINIFS and MAXIFS

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use pivot table:

[image]